# How to return unique elements in list of tuple as another tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, comparison, combinations

Assume I have list of tuples `a=[(0,1),(2,0),(1,4)]` and I want to return unique element of each two tuples as a new tuple. For example `(0,1)` and `(2,0)` returns`(1,2)`. Also `(0,1)` and `(1,4)` return `(0,4)`.

Therefore, output is `unique=[(1,2),(0,4)]`

I tried code below but it seems I am not in correct path:

```
from itertools import combinations
a=[(0,1),(2,0),(1,4)]

b=list(combinations(a,2))
def myComp(pair1, pair2):
    if any(x == y for x, y in zip(pair1, pair2)):
        return(pair1,pair2)

d=[]
for i in range(len(b)):
    c=myComp(b[i][0],b[i][1])
    d.append(c)
```

Comment: could you elaborate on why 2 pairs return that specific pair? what makes things unique?

Comment: i think because the numbers in the pair returned are not repeated anywhere for two given pairs @Ironkey

Comment: oh i didnt see that, let me write up an answer!

Comment: because for example in pairs (0,1) and (2,0), 0 is common in both of them. Then it should return uncommon elements which is (1,2).

Comment: so i already see one problem, you're also comparing `(2,0)` and `(1,4)` in which ALL elements are unique, how do you handle such cases?

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: what does ```(2,0),(1,4)``` return

Comment: as he said, nothing

Comment: I cant see where @Ironkey they are all unique?

Comment: in `(2,0), (1,4)` all elements are unique; `2` is not in `(1,4)` & `0` is not in `(1,4)`

Comment: oh he said it in the comments thanks @Ironkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crude answer without any list comps:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)]

uniques = []
for x, y in combinations(a,2):
    z = []
    for i in x:
        if i not in y:
           z.append(i)
    for i in y:
        if i not in x:
           z.append(i)
    if len(z) == 2:
        uniques.append(tuple(z))

print(list(set(uniques)))
```

```
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (1, 2), (0, 4), (3, 4), (0, 3), (2, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: the code makes duplications. for example for list a=a=[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)] it outputs (1,2) and (2,1). Can you please return one of them. Also, return same tuples like two (1,3).

Comment: `(2,1)` technically isnt a duplicate of `(1,2)`

Comment: seeing as you accepted this *please note* that @Pranav Hosangadi posted an answer that is far more efficient and does the same thing, all you have to do to make these the same is pass the output of what you get from his to `list(set(output)))`

Answer (score 2):

First, convert all the tuples in `a` to sets.

```
a2 = [set(i) for i in a]
```

Then, take combinations of two elements of `a2`.

```
b2 = itertools.combinations(a2, 2)
# print(list(b2)) gives:
# [({0, 1}, {0, 2}), ({0, 1}, {1, 4}), ({0, 2}, {1, 4})]
```

Then, for every pair in `b2`, find the symmetric difference.

```
answer = [tuple(x ^ y) for x, y in b2]
# answer: [(1, 2), (0, 4), (0, 1, 2, 4)]
```

Like Ironkey mentions in the comments, you get `(0, 1, 2, 4)` in the last element because you're comparing `(0, 2)` and `(1, 4)`, and all elements in these tuples are mutually exclusive.

To filter out the four-element tuples, you can simply add that condition:

```
answer_f = [x for x in answer if len(x) == 2]
# answer_f: [(1, 2), (0, 4)]
```

Comment: All tuples length should be two.

Comment: @Aras then your problem is badly defined. In the last combination, you're comparing (0, 2) and (1, 4), and all elements in these tuples are mutually exclusive. Which two are you supposed to select? Or do you want to include the answer _only if_ this operation gives a two-element tuple?

Comment: if you run my code with given list [(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)] c gives 10 pairs of tuple and then I want 10 unique tuple out of them.

Comment: Your problem is horrifically defined... if you want an output list with the length of the input list this will not work with what you have given us as your first input... `[(0,1),(2,0),(1,4)]` will only be able to return `[(1, 2), (0, 4)]` (length of 2)

Comment: @Ironkey I rolled back your edit because OP can put those lines together themselves if they want. Combining a bunch of lines into a single line makes it a pain to read and debug, so I'd rather OP go through that exercise themselves if they really want to, instead of giving them that function.

Comment: thats all good, i thought they just might want it in function format but its definetely better for them to put it together especially with their lack of understanding in this situation

Comment: @Aras I don't understand what you mean. You seem to want the unique elements from each combination of tuples. A list of 10 tuples will have 10C2 = 45 combinations. The 10-element list you gave has 15 of these combinations that contain 2-element unique tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use packages.

The conditions `if i != x and a.index(i)<a.index(x)` make sure we aren't comparing identical tuples and also we are comparing the same pair of tuples once

Then we just grab the element of they are not in the other tuple

The condition `if len(m) == 2 and sorted(m) in uniq` makes sure that the list is only 2 elements long, and also solves your comment about having `(2,1) & (1,2)`

```
a=[(0,1),(2,0),(1,4),(0,2)]

uniq = []
for i in a:
  for x in a:
    if i != x and a.index(i)<a.index(x):
      m = [y for y in i if y not in x] + [z for z in x if z not in i]
      if len(m) == 2 and tuple(sorted(m)) not in uniq:
        uniq.append(tuple(m))

print(uniq)

>>> [(1, 2), (0, 4)]
```